# Unable to validate DATE format due to Msg 8116

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have `TRANSACTIONS` table with col `BUSINESS_DATE` (varchar 255).

```
distinct LEN(BUSINESS_DATE) = 6 and 8
--Sample data for BUSINESS_DATE
071312   --mmddyy for LEN = 6
08012012 --mmddyyyy for LEN = 8
```

I want to load these dates in TABLE SUNNY as DATE. Here is my CASE statement -

```
select CASE WHEN LEN(BUSINESS_DATE) = 6
                THEN CAST('20' + RIGHT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],2) + LEFT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],4) AS DATE)
                WHEN LEN(BUSINESS_DATE) = 8
                THEN CAST(RIGHT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],4) + LEFT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],4) AS DATE)
                END                                                AS TRANS_DT
    into SUNNY
    from TRANSACTIONS GRAND
```

All records were loaded. Now when I try to execute below query to test date format, it throws error Msg 8116. Can anybody **explain** what is wrong here and **how** can I test it?

```
select top 5 * from
SUNNY
where ISDATE(TRANS_DT) = 1
```

Comment: If the column `SUNNY.TRANS_DT` is a date type (and I think your question says it is), the fact that all records were loaded without casting errors proves that your dates are valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISDATE function can't use a DATE as it's argument; the documentation states that the parameter:

> Is a character string or expression that can be converted to a
>   character string. The expression must be less than 4,000 characters.
>   Date and time data types, except datetime and smalldatetime, are not
>   allowed as the argument for ISDATE.

So either cast the values to DATETIME instead of DATE in the select statement, or cast the parameter for ISDATE to NVARCHAR.

**The test seems unnecessary though as the result from the SELECT...INTO should be a proper date, or the cast would have failed and no data would have been inserted into SUNNY.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to insert into sunny table. then check
 If GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE] column is a varchar type then remove convert function.

```
select CASE WHEN LEN(BUSINESS_DATE) = 6
            THEN CAST('20' + convert(varchar(5),RIGHT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],2))+'-'+ LEFT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],2)+'-'+substring(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],3,2)) AS DATE)
            WHEN LEN(BUSINESS_DATE) = 8
            THEN CAST(RIGHT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],4) + RIGHT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],2))+'-'+ LEFT(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],2)+'-'+substring(GRAND.[BUSINESS_DATE],3,2)) AS DATE)
            END                                                AS TRANS_DT
into SUNNY
from TRANSACTIONS GRAND
```

Comment: I didnt had a chance to check for syntax error. so there is a possibiblity to get syntax errors